# Multiple applications using GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I want to write (but first I want to understand how to do it) applications (more than one) based on GStreamer framework that would share the same hardware resource at the same time.

For example: there is a hardware with HW acceleration for video decoding. I want to start simultaneously two applications that are able to decode different video streams, using HW acceleration. Of course I assume that HW is able to handle such requests, there is appropriate driver (but not GStreamer element) for doing this, but how to write GStreamer element that would support such resource sharing between separate processes?

I would appreciate any links, suggestions where to start...

Comment: Perhaps a gstreamer multiplexer (mux) might be a place to start?

Answer (score 1):

You have h/w that can be accessed concurrently. Hence two gstreamer elements accessing it concurrently should work! There is nothing Gstreamer specific here.

Say you wanted to write a decoding element, it is like any decoding element and you access your hardware correctly. Your drivers should take care of the concurrent access.
The starting place is the Gstreamer plugin writer's guide.

Comment: Thanx for reply, but what I mean is that there is one phisical video decoder, that is able to decode a few streams (by multiplexing decoding). It is visible via API-lib accessible in userspace. I have library that allows me to open 2 'virtual' vid decoders, but only if I do it in one process I know that I used vid0 and vid1 is free for example. I need some kind of 'manager' of instances of virtual video decoders that would serve instances to requesting processes...

Comment: You should ideally have a query also available. If not you can pass the vid0 and vid1 as arguments to the program instance so that the application can control which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

So you need a single process that controls the HW decoder, and decodes streams from multiple sources.

I would recommend building a daemon, possibly itself based on GStreamer also. The gdppay and gdpdepay provide quite simple ways to pass data through sockets to the daemon and back. The daemon would wait for connections on a specified port (or unix socket) and open a virtual decoder per each connection. The video decoder elements in the separate applications would internally connect to the daemon and get back the decoded video.